# Unable to access vector value by index

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class Stack
{
    public:
        int top;
        vector<int> v;
        Stack(int size)
        {
            top=0;
            cout<<"Enter the values"<<endl;
            for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
            {
                int val;
                cin>>val;
                v.push_back(val);
                top++;
            }
        }
        void push(int val)
        {
            v.push_back(val);
            top++;
        }
        int pop()
        {
            int x=v[top];
            top--;
            return x;
        }
        void disp()
        {
            for(int j=top; j<=0; j--)
                cout<<v[j]<<' ';
        }
};

int main()
{
    Stack s(3);
    int k=s.pop();
    cout<<k;
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to learn the basics of OOP.

Here, my Stack constructor and push function are working fine, but there is a problem with the pop and disp functions.
I'm assuming that I am using an incorrect syntax to access the elements of a vector(maybe?). Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Also, the value of k always comes out to be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a off-by-one index error.

The way you have implemented your class, when there are `N` items in the stack, the value of `top` is `N`.

Hence, `top` is not a valid index to access the elements of `v`. You can use:

```
int pop()
{
    int x=v[top-1];
    top--;
    return x;
}
```

or

```
int pop()
{
    top--;
    int x=v[top];
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the vector functions

```
int k = s.back();
s.pop_back();
cout << k;
```

more informationhttp://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/back/

Answer (score 1):

As some of the other answers say, you can use the built-in vector functions to do these things (see [`pop_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/pop_back/) and [`back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/back/).

However, if you want to define your own, I would use the `vector.at(index)` function. Addressing the values with the index as you have works, but it doesn't do any bounds checking `at()` does. Which would solve your problem above where your index isn't correct for the zero-based indexing of a vector.